# Installing Redmine on Centos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, centos, redmine

I'm following this guide for installing Redmine on CentOS. I've followed every step.
Redmine currently runs on WebBrick but not on Apache.

I've successfully install passenger. I got this message:

```
Please edit your Apache configuration file, and add these lines:

LoadModule passenger_module /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-4.0.0.rc4/libout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-4.0.0.rc4
PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby

After you restart Apache, you are ready to deploy any number of Ruby on Rails
applications on Apache, without any further Ruby on Rails-specific
configuration!
```

When I restart the Apache server, I get this message.

```
[root@localhost httpd]# service httpd restart
Stopping httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting httpd: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using localhost.localdomain for ServerName
[Mon Mar 25 08:02:58 2013] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
                                                           [  OK  ]
```

Maybe this has something to do with why it isn't working.

Here is the config file:

```
[root@localhost conf.d]# cat redmine.conf 
# Loading Passenger
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-4.0.0.rc4/libout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-4.0.0.rc4
PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName localhost.localdomain
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/redmine/public
   <Directory /var/www/html/redmine/public>
      # This relaxes Apache security settings.
      AllowOverride all
      # MultiViews must be turned off.
      Options -MultiViews
      allow from all
   </Directory>

   ErrorLog "|/usr/sbin/rotatelogs /etc/httpd/logs/redmine-error.%Y-%m-%d.log 86400"
   CustomLog "|/usr/sbin/rotatelogs /etc/httpd/logs/redmine-access.%Y-%m-%d.log 86400" "%h %l %u %t %D \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\""

</VirtualHost>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide your Apache configuration file. There is something wrong with it...

Comment: Can you confirm that the message you got, you actually added those lines to your configuration as requested? The errors you got are mostly innocuous but can you explain what is actually going wrong for you? Does apache give you an error for the virtual host redmine should be on? What about Apache logs, any error output you can provide?

Comment: I've updated the question with the config file

Comment: When I navigate to the site I get this... 
http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=217a012

Comment: What did you change compared to the information above?

Comment: I just found that the config file had the redmine folder set to /var/www/redmine
while I have it as /var/www/html/redmine
I made the change and now I get this http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=382baaf

Comment: You really need to learn to be more specific... From the given information man can only guess if you have a working state now, or if the config you pasted above is really the one you are working with.

Comment: Any `.htaccess` stuff present?

Comment: sorry for not being specific enough. I haven't done any .htaccess.

Comment: I've updated the question with the current config file. With this config, I get the 403 Forbidden message when I navigate to it.

Answer (score 1):

What is the version of your apache web server?
I'm guessing that perhaps this problem is from apache version.

Answer (score 0):

This is my vhost config.

```
<VirtualHost my.url.de:80>

   ServerName my.url.de:80

   ServerAdmin mail@url.de

   DocumentRoot /var/www/redmine/redmine-2.0.3/public


   <Directory /var/www/redmine/redmine-2.0.3/public>
       AllowOverride All
       Options -MultiViews
       allow from all
   </Directory>


   ErrorLog /var/log/redmine-2.0.3/error_log
   CustomLog /var/log/redmine-2.0.3/access common


</VirtualHost>
```

This works, maybe do not use `<VirtualHost *:80>`? Then the error message on `service httpd restart` should just go away.

If this is not solving it:
A problem I had was you need to have proper access to the logs:

- They must exist and
- your apache user must have RW on them.

Since I use a special Apache setup with one dedicated user per vhost (conf line here omitted), this might not be a problem for you. Mentioning it still, just in case, since it took me very long to track this error down, there were no messages about that problem to be found anywhere.

In your case, try more basic log files to preclude them to be the error cause.